# Get Item ID and Name Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I need to get the name and id's from all the items that i have in one folder !

I Cant Use caml query !
Can someone tell how can i do it without using caml query ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this. hope this works

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://serverName/sites/Vijai/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Custom");
                if (list != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Also you can use recursive scope.

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = fldr;
//Recursive Scope....
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
SPListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
int filecount = allitems.Count;
```

Comment: I try to use the 1 way you sugest and i have this eror coming:


Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.